# Segmentation Fault when Looping over Allocated Memory

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc

I'm making a hash table in C whose keys are of the type char*. I'm storing the key in the table itself for reasons outside the scope of this problem. The hash table is working for the most part, except for the following issue: when the table size is over 2112 elements and I try to initialize the keys as NULL pointers, I run into a segmentation fault.

Here is the definition of the hashTable:

```
typedef struct hash_table
{
  uint32_t size;  // # of elements the table can store
  uint32_t count; // # of elements in the table
  char **keys;    // The pointer to the first key. Each key is a char*
  int32_t *vals;  // The pointer to the first val.
} hashTable;
```

and here is where I initialize the table with NULL pointers as keys:

```
// Declare the pointer to the hash table
hashTable *symbolTable = malloc(sizeof(hashTable));

// Set the hash table properties
symbolTable->size = 7699;
symbolTable->count = 0;
symbolTable->keys = malloc(sizeof(symbolTable->keys[0]) * symbolTable->size);
symbolTable->vals = malloc(sizeof(symbolTable->vals[0]) * symbolTable->size);

// Initialize the keys to be NULL pointers.
int i;
for (i = 0; i < symbolTable->size; i++)
{
  char **cp = symbolTable->keys + i * sizeof(symbolTable->keys[0]);
  *cp = NULL;
}
```

When I run the program, I get a segmentation fault in the for loop when i==2111.

I am relatively new to dynamic memory allocation in C, and have been stuck on this problem for some time. If anybody has any insight or advice I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When setting `cp`, you don't need to multiply `i` by `sizeof`. Pointer arithmetic automatically multiplies by the size of the object that the pointer points to. The result is that you were multiplying twice, so you were writing far outside the array bounds. So it should be

```
char **cp = symbolTable->keys + i;
```

But you can simply use normal array indexing instead:

```
symbolTable->keys[i] = NULL;
```